# Scheduled emails from Gmail

Tags: gmail

I would like to send scheduled emails from my Gmail even when my computer is turned off. Is it possible?

Comment: It seems Yandex.com does it. Testing now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need fewer than 10/month then http://www.boomeranggmail.com is free.

For alternatives, check out http://alternativeto.net/software/boomerang-for-gmail/

Answer (score -1):

Yandex.com offers the option for free. An email must be scheduled for sending within a year from the scheduling.